# Eclipse syntax / theme color reset

Tags: eclipse

I was tired of the **>>bright<<** classic theme in Eclipse and tried to change this using the eclipse window themes and Moonrise theme plugin.

This didn't work at all and broke several colors in Eclipse. So i deleted the plugin, reset Eclipse window theme

> Window -> preferences -> apperance Theme: Classic, color and font
>   theme: Classic.

But this dosen't reset my html and css syntax color. Which now is light yellow and light blue on white. And i can't see in preferences where i can revert the syntax for this to default.

I have also tried to delete the .metadata in my workspace and delete the eclipse folder entirely and downloading a fresh install (quick solution?). But when i start Eclipse again it from somewhere import the old dark theme in its startup process thus again breaking the theme and syntax coloring.

How do i just revert back to a fresh standard Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the files created by Eclipse in \users\Username* along with the projects .metadata file and download a new clean install of the Eclipse directory from where the .exe file runs. Which solved the problem